# SharePoint group in Person/Group Picker

Tags: email, groups, people-picker, initiation-form

I want to send an email from a reusable workflow to everybody in a SharePoint group. I created a test group from the site permissions and created a reusable workflow. In this workflow I added a initiation form parameter that is a Person/Group Picker and made it a required field that allows multiple values. Then in an email i set the recipients of the to the workflow parameter, semi-colon delimited.

Now, I created a test library and added the reusable workflow (with the process requiring me to add at least one value in the picker. I searched and found the SharePoint group I created.) Then, when I attempt to manually start the workflow, I get the Form Initiation form with the group pre-entered. This is great, what I want. I can then add more individual users to the picker and send the email.

The problem comes in that only then persons added in the picker receive the email, nobody in the group. I guess the problem I'm having is converting the persons in a SharePoint permission group to a list of email addresses.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format as Display Names semi-colon delimited seems to work.

[image]